# Python Issue with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, output

Please help me with this code, ven if i enter the correct answer that is \'9'\ in `user_input`, the `messagebox` i am getting is "You Have Lost", instead of "You Have Won".

Any help will be appreciated, thank you all.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

magic = str(9)
rt = Tk()

def roll():
    if user_input == magic:
        messagebox._show("Congratulation", "You Have Won!!")
    else:
        messagebox._show("Try Again", "You Have Lost!!")

label1 = Label(rt , text = "Enter Your Number Here: ").pack()
user_input = Entry(rt).pack()
btn1 = Button(rt, text = "Click", command = roll).pack()

rt.mainloop()
```

Comment: the value of `user_input` is `None` and that of `magic` is `9`, hence the if condition is bound to fail

Answer (score 1):

Your `user_input` is `None` since `pack()` method returns `None` and you are setting it equal to `user_input`.
One way to resolve this is to get the text value of the entry within the function.

```py
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox

magic = str(9)
rt = Tk()


def roll():
    user_input = entry.get()  # getting the text value of the entry widget
    if user_input == magic:
        messagebox._show("Congratulation", "You Have Won!!")
    else:
        messagebox._show("Try Again", "You Have Lost!!")


label1 = Label(rt, text="Enter Your Number Here: ").pack()
entry = Entry(rt)  # set this equal to the variable, not with the execution of pack()
entry.pack()
btn1 = Button(rt, text="Click", command=roll).pack()

rt.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

don't write `Entry.pack()`

`Entry` is class, it creates an instance (let's call it `i1`)
by executing `it.pack()` you place it on the window, but return `None`

so basically you're saying

```
Entry().pack()
user_input = None
```

save `Entry` instance in the variable (say `e1`)
and get user_input **inside `roll` function** by
`user_uinput = e1.get()`

also, I recommend using oop to work with tkinter, but it's ok to start without